# MySQL - AND / OR logic - what's wrong?

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out what's wrong with this query. I want all productIDs from specific sellers that are no longer valid. To be "valid," a product has to be active='Y' AND expireDate>=NOW() AND statusid = 20 (among several other not valid).

Here's the query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(productID) FROM products
    WHERE sellerID IN
    (/*list of sellerIDs*/) 
    AND (active != 'Y' OR statusid != 20 OR expireDate < NOW())
```

And some example data (all from sellerIDs in the subquery above)

```
    productID | active | statusid | expireDate
    1         |   Y    |     20   | 2015-08-01
    2         |   N    |     20   | 2015-08-01
    3         |   Y    |     0    | 2015-08-01
    4         |   Y    |     20   | 2015-07-01
```

I expect to get 2, 3 and 4 as a result.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? At a glance, the logic in the AND appears to be correct.

Comment: status = 20 or statusid ?
That's not the same for me

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: All 4 rows! it's driving me mad, it must be some silly (big) mistake I can't see.

Comment: Separate out each condition inside the parens and test them individually to see if you are getting the correct results.

Comment: The point is that if I run "SELECT * FROM products where active = 'Y' AND statusid = 20 AND expireDate >= NOW()" I get productID 1 . Therefore I expect my initial query to return 2, 3, 4.

Comment: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e9bd/2

Comment: could it then be that the IN clause is causing the issue being in AND with the other condintions?

Comment: can you show your IN clause?

Comment: post your table structure too, there might be some issue with data type, as your query looks well

Answer (score 0):

So in the problem statement it says we need AND between active, statusid and expireDate. Please use below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productID) FROM products
WHERE sellerID IN
(/*list of sellerIDs*/) 
AND active != 'Y' AND statusid != 20 AND expireDate < NOW()
```

Comment: No, because all three conditions would have to be met. In my situation only one could be met (e.g. active = 'N') but the other too might be "valid" (e.g. statusid = 20 and expireDate >= NOW())

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote the answer for all valid products. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productID) FROM products
WHERE sellerID IN (/*list of sellerIDs*/) 
AND active != 'Y' OR statusid != 20 OR DATE(expireDate) < NOW();
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productID) FROM products
WHERE sellerID IN (/*list of sellerIDs*/) 
AND active != 'Y' AND statusid != 20 OR DATE(expireDate) < DATE(NOW());
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productID) FROM products
WHERE sellerID IN (/*list of sellerIDs*/) 
AND active != 'Y' OR (statusid != 20 OR DATE(expireDate) < CURDATE());
```